# Set default page on MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost

I'm trying to work on a project which name is Voat.

Here is the of this project https://github.com/voat/voat

I cloned the project and build it on my localhost which is "/inetpub/" folder. 
Now when I'm trying to reach localhost I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

So first question how can I set default page on this project?
Here is the RouteConfig.cs for Voat solution: [RouteConfig.cs](https://github.com/voat/voat/blob/Core/src/Voat.UI/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs)
and [appsettings.json](https://github.com/voat/voat/blob/Core/src/Voat.UI/~appsettings.json).

I think we need to set this https://github.com/voat/voat/blob/Core/src/Voat.UI/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml file as a Default Page but I really don't know how to do it.

There is a little instroduction for installing Voat but its outdated but it may help if you want to check it: [Master Branch -outdated-](https://github.com/voat/voat/tree/master)

If you want to install Voat on your localhost to help me you should use the Core branch on Github. And if you success to install Voat on your localhost could you please explain me how to do it step by step? Thank you everyone already.

Comment: Have you tried any of the millions of pages you get when you Google "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."?

Comment: Yes I've tried that... Same result, when I activated the list the contents directory it just listing the files. I can't set the default start page for this project.